# How to center align buttons from their middle, rather than left axis

Tags: html, css

I make a button, put it in a div, center align the div and button, however the button aligns itself from its far left side which makes it appear off center. Is there a way to make it align from wherever its actual center is?

```css
.btndiv{
width: 80%;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;

}


.testbutton{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 30%;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="btndiv">
<button class=" testbutton"> A button </button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define its position in `left:50%;` i.e,. to the center then  add `transform:translateX(50%);` to the element so that it will cut the unwanted space automatically aligns the item to the center.

```css
.btndiv{
width: 80%;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;

}


.testbutton{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 30%;
height: 50px;
left:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="btndiv">
<button class=" testbutton"> A button </button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using flexbox:

Here is the updated code snippet:

```css
.btndiv {
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.testbutton {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="btndiv">
    <button class=" testbutton"> A button </button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For aligning element, its always recommended to use "grid", example in snippet:

```css
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    }
    .grid-item {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>  
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><button class=" testbutton"> A Button </button>
    </div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>  
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>  
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below css and you're done...

```
.testbutton {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Also, If you want to center align it vertically add below css

```
.testbutton {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```css
.btndiv{
width: 80%;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;

}

.testbutton {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.testbutton{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 30%;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="btndiv">
<button class=" testbutton"> A button </button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```